# regular expression repeating the first 3 characters

Tags: regex

Hello guys i tried searching the site but i couldnt really find or understand the regular expression i am looking for.

My regular express has be to be lets 3-7 letters followed by SALE or OFF the year 4 digits 
and then the first 3 initial letters inputed.

**for instance: hamcookOFF2012ham**

my regular expression code is

**(regexp="\D{3,7}(OFF|SALE)\d{4}"**

that enables me to get until the year but how can i get the first 3 characters?

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: the first 3 so forexample ham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to achieve this, I recommend the following:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]{0,4}(OFF|SALE)\d{4}\1
```

- `\1` matches the same text that was matched by the first capturing group.

**Note:** `\D` matches non-digit characters ( *all but `0-9`* ), use `[a-zA-Z]` to strictly match letter characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the first 3 letters using a group (in parentheses) and refer to it as follows:

```
(\D{3})\D{0,4}(OFF|SALE)\d{4}\1
```

The `\D{3}` surrounded in parentheses will be saved in a group numbered 1 and the backreference `\1` refers to whatever is matched by this group.

**Note**: `\D` will also match special characters like a comma or an underscore. If only letters are to be matched, use `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: If you're doing this inside a Java program, you need to code a double backslash, e.g. "\\D", for each backslash in the regexp. Otherwise the string parser will throw out the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a regex which matches against a reference to a previous capture-group.  Below, `\1` is a back-reference to the first capture-group (which is the first three non-digits):

```
^(\D{3})(\D{0,4})(OFF|SALE)\d{4}(\1)$
```